# Wifi network keeps asking for password

Tags: wireless

Like the questions says.

I'm pretty sure my password is correct, but every time I enter it, it asks for it again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I don't know if a diagnose would be helpful right now. The problem seems temporary, and it has stopped. But an answer would be helpful in case it happens again.

Comment: While it is happening run the script from the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while ago. What I did to resolve it was go in to the network manager and edit the wirless manager. I had to change mine from wlan0 to eth1. It is weird but it worked.